# Selenium List of Element to match.unable to format Array value

Tags: arrays, selenium, webdriver, element

I have been trying to validate the 2 list of the array value. one will be given manually and another one will retrieve from Webelement from the website. the output should be like below as expected but actual values display lot of , and space. please help me

Expected Values  :`[ITV,ITV2,ITVBe,ITV4,CITV]`

Actual Values :`[Actual Values :[, ITV, , , ITV2, , , ITVBe, , , ITV3, , , ITV4, , , CITV, ]`

Code below :

```
public static void verifyTVChannels(String channels)
{

    List<String> tvchannels= Arrays.asList(channels);

    System.out.println("Expected Values  :"+tvchannels);

    List<String> actual =new ArrayList<String>();


    System.out.print("Actual Values :[");
    for(WebElement e: TVHomePage.itvChannels)
    {
              actual.add(e.getText());

    }

    System.out.print("Actual Values :"+actual);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------ ");

}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing in the above solution?

Comment: The Actual Values :[, ITV, , , ITV2, , , ITVBe, , , ITV3, , , ITV4, , , CITV, ] is having lot of , value. I am expecting [ITV,ITV2,ITVBe,ITV4,CITV]

Comment: You can use contains method in string to compare the two values and get it done. I you need any help on using contains method, kindly let me know

Comment: Santhosh - can you explain how to use contains method for above scenario, please

Comment: Post the URL of the site. It looks like your locator is not specific enough and is finding empty or hidden elements accounting for the blank entries in your list.

Comment: Hi Jeffc, the url is https://www.itv.com/

Comment: HI jeffc, I have 2 scenarios to test. 1, to check all the ITV channels (ITV-ITV2-ITVBe-ITV3,ITV4,CITV) are correctly displayed. 2, Count and print on the console all the Shows that start with "A". I have been struggling to find the locator and values. please help me

Answer (score 0):

store both the actual and expected values in an array as below.

```
String[] actual = x.toArray(new String[x.size()]);//x is an arraylist
String[] expected = y.toArray(new String[y.size()]);//Y is the expected list
```

Construct a for loop and check the elements in each array.

```
for(int i = 0; i< actual.length;i++)
{
   if(actual[i].contains(expected[i]))
   {
      System.out.println(actual[i]+' '+ expected[i]+' '+"matches");
   }
   else
   {
      //doesn't match
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps. thanks.

Comment: Still no luck, It is throwing array exception

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
    List<String> tvchannels= Arrays.asList(channels);

    System.out.println("Expected Values  :"+tvchannels);

    List<String> actual =new ArrayList<String>();


    System.out.print("Actual Values :[");
    for(WebElement e: TVHomePage.itvChannels)
    {
        if(!e.getText().trim().isEmpty())
              actual.add(e.getText().trim());

    }

    System.out.print("Actual Values :"+actual);

    if(actual.containsAll(tvchannels)){
        System.out.println("matching");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("not matching");
    }
```

Comment: Murthi , I am still getting wrong output below  Expected Values  :[ITV,ITV2,ITVbe,ITV4,CITV]
Actual Values :[not matching
Actual Values :[, , , , ITV2, , , ITVBe, , , ITV3, , , ITV4, , , CITV, ]

Comment: I am expecting same output as expected values

Comment: have you updated the code. can you please share the code

Comment: Thanks, murthi. we are nearly there. still, space is there after each character  Expected Values  :[ITV,ITV2,ITVbe,ITV4,CITV]
Actual Values :[not matching
Actual Values :[ITVBe, ITV3, ITV4, CITV]

Comment: have you added the trim method to get text it will work.

Comment: Have added please see my code but System.out.print("Actual Values :[");
        for(WebElement e: ITVHomePage.itvChannels)
        {
            //List<String> itvchannels= Arrays.asList(itvCh);
             if(!e.getText().trim().isEmpty())
            actual.add(e.getText().trim());
    } but output is  [ITVBe, ITV3, ITV4, CITV]  i am expecting no space in ago   edit   
     
have you [ITV,ITV2,ITVbe,ITV4,CITV]

Comment: there is no space actually.  while printing, java console will add the space.

Comment: In that case, how will I change my expected condition value same as actual value

Comment: I am added dummy values and compared it is working fine. it is matching.

Comment: String exp[]={"ITV","ITV2","ITVBe","ITV4","CITV"};
      List<String> exp1=new ArrayList<String>();
      exp1=Arrays.asList(exp);
      Collections.sort(exp1);
      List<String> act=new ArrayList<String>();
      act.add("");
      act.add(" ITV".trim());
      act.add("");
      act.add("");
      act.add(" ITV2".trim());
      act.add("");
      act.add(" ITVBe".trim());
      act.add("");
      act.add(" ITV4".trim());
      act.add("");
      act.add(" CITV".trim());
      Collections.sort(act);
      System.out.println(" ".trim().isEmpty());

Comment: System.out.println(exp);
      System.out.println(act);System.out.println(act.containsAll(exp1));
      This is my dummy code

Comment: Thanks murthi. very helpful